# In Objective-C when can I use a primitive data type instead of NSNumber?

Tags: objective-c

I was recently writing a program in Objective-C and I tried the wrote the following part of a line where 'someString' is an instance of NSString:

```
[someString substringFromIndex:3];
```

The compiler seems okay with this but I'm not exactly sure why.  The documentation for the `substringFromIndex` method says that the parameter has to be an `NSUInteger` however, isn't 3 just a primitive integer?  Why can I do this?  (Note, I'm new to Objective-C so I'm sure the reasoning is very simple or I'm just wrong about something.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NSUInteger` is typedef'd to a primitive type. Which type it is depends on the processor you're compiling for.

As seen [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html) (and pasted below):

```
#if __LP64__ || TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64 
    typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else 
    typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

`NSNumber` and `NSUInteger` are two different types. As CajunLuke indicates, `NSUInteger` (like `NSInteger`) is a typedef on standard C primitive types, but `NSNumber` is an object class. `NSNumber` and `NSInteger`/`NSUInteger` are not interchangeable, but `NSInteger`/`NSUInteger` are generally interchangeable with regular C int/long.